# [SOLVED]Undefined symbols whilst building cesium in xcode

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, cesiumjs

i am currently using Unity 2022.3.8f1 and XCode 14.2 and ARCore SDK for IOS 1.39 and Cesium(Latest) and Geospatial Creator to build an ar project. While building on XCode i get undefined symbol errors similiar to down below:

-Undefined symbol: Cesium3DTilesReader::SchemaReader::SchemaReader()
-Undefined symbol: Cesium3DTilesReader::GroupMetadataReader::GroupMetadataReader()
...
I had a similiar issue with arcore but i found the necessary sdk for that and imported that package to my xcode project however i can't find any packages for cesium to import. Do i need to upgrade my MacBook Air 2017 to be able to build an app to my iphone or is it some kind of package issue, build issue etc.

I've set the Bitcode to no in every part of the project, i've added -ObjC to other linker flags. I've tried the most of the advice on the internet but none of them seems to be solving the issue or they are simply outdated for the newer versions of those sdk's.

Comment: I faced same problem and couldn’t find a solution.
report with close issue
https://github.com/CesiumGS/cesium-unity/issues/362

Comment: And now I downgraded Cesium for Unity to 1.4.0 and then it worked.

Comment: Thank you, i've downgraded some of the packages but it made the app unstable so i pulled the commit from the link you provided and solved the stability issue.